# How to add items in unordered list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Recently I was asked to update / maintain asp.net web app. I am new to this technology and so far I am doing this task as google assisted programmer, with maximum help from this forum. I did not ask single question so far on c# as I got lot of help on this forum.  Basically I am not a real programmer but I must do it as this task is assigned to me and I am very much keen to learn this.

This page is written in C# and I am stuck with a problem of creating list items "li" for the pagination. I got (pagination logic) a code which works correctly using response.write method. But I want to populate li's with page numbers and links. I may add link buttons instead of hyperlinks once I understand how to generate collection of html controls programmatically.

My code is as follows

```
int startPage = (curPage < 5) ? 1 : curPage - 4;
int endPage = 4 + startPage;
endPage = (totalPage < endPage) ? totalPage : endPage;
diff = startPage - endPage + 4;
startPage -= (startPage - diff > 0) ? diff : 0;

if (startPage > 1) Response.Write(" First ... ");
for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) { Response.Write(i); }
if (endPage < totalPage) Response.Write(" ... Last ");
```

I am getting output like

```
12345 ... Last
```

Now I want convert this plain text output into collection of "li".

I have tried many things but I am not able to add "li" one by one with c# code. Basically I couldn't understand programming concept of adding "li" for

```
<ul id="pagenav" runat="server></ul>
```

Can somebody teach / help / demonstrate how to add these "li" to "ul" with reference to this pagination logic.

Comment: something along the lines of `Response.Write(string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", i));`?

Comment: First things first... what control are you paging? Some .net controls have paging built in so you may just need to enable paging for the control, e.g. for a gridview "myGridView.AllowPaging"

Comment: Typically you query a database for the data, then you could 'bind' it to a .net control such as a gridview, then enable paging for the gridview... et voila... for gridview binding see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=VS.110%29.aspx for gridview paging see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx

Comment: These pages are corresponding images stored in folders. There is no database involved in this app. Each time while showing these images, we are finding total images and pagination is displayed for navigation of these images. Thus images are as good as a pages but web page (aspx) is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant code modified to use HtmlGenericControl

```
HtmlGenericControl liControl;

if (startPage > 1) {
    liControl = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    liControl.InnerHtml = "First...";
    pagenav.Controls.Add(liControl);
}

for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) { 
    liControl = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    liControl.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
    pagenav.Controls.Add(liControl);
}

if (endPage < totalPage) {
    liControl = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    liControl.InnerHtml = "...Last";
    pagenav.Controls.Add(liControl);
}
```

Comment: Bravo, your code worked perfectly. I need to adjust my pagination logic little bit. I just copy/pasted your code and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks,  I have closed it. I have added link buttons in your code and now it is working fine in web app as I was planning to make.

Answer (score 1):

Below logic works for your problem..

```
Response.Write("<ul id='pagenav' runat='server'>");
for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) { 
    Response.Write("<li>" + i.ToString() + "</li>");
}
Response.Write("</ul>");
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<ul id='pagenav' runat='server'>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, I could have implemented your logic but with Nikhil's suggested code my work became almost zero. I learned another technique of generating control from your comment.